# Javascript function parameter in curling braces

Tags: javascript

What is the difference in parameter processing between these 2 `startTimer()` function calls?

```
<img src="/static/loading.gif" onload="startTimer('<timer_value>');" />
```

and

```
<img src="/static/loading.gif" onload="startTimer('{{ timer }}');" />
```

Comment: I don't really see a difference - in both cases a string is passed as the parameter - the parameters will be "processed" as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

- They are just characters in strings. They have no special meaning that isn't given to them by the function being called.
- The HTML you are showing us is run through a template parser before being delivered to the browser so the special meaning will be given to them by the template language rather than the JavaScript.